# Tmux external clipboard interaction with loadb over SSH

Tags: ssh, tmux, clipboard, kitty

I have the external clipboard option enabled:

```bash
$ tmux show-options -g -s set-clipboard

set-clipboard external
```

And I'm using Kitty terminal with tmux in SSH.

When I highlight text with the mouse or use `<C-B>[`, the contents get copied to my system clipboard just fine, and I can paste it back into tmux using `<C-B>]`. However, when I pipe as follows:

```bash
$ echo -n "Hello World" | tmux loadb -
```

The contents are correct for `<C-B>]`, i.e. when I paste within tmux, but my system clipboard is not updated. I can't figure out why that is, shouldn't it be the same behavior?